# How to prove that " necessarily (A OR ~A) " does not imply " necessarily A OR necessarily ~A".

Tags: logic, modal-logic

In *De Interpretatione* , Aristotle criticizes logical fatalism ( a metaphysical doctrine professed in the Megarian School, in particular by Diodorus Cronus).

Aristotle reconstructs the reasoning of logical fatalists as follow :

(1) Necessarily ( there will be a sea battle tomorrow or there will not be a sea battle tomorrow).

(2) Therefore, necessarily a sea battle will happen tomorrow or necessarily it will not happen.

One can say informally that the logical mistake consists in the fact that " the necessity of the disjunction does not imply the disjunction of the necessities".

However, how to prove rigorously using the tools of modal logic that the reasoning is not valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide a semantics for 'necessarily $A$' by saying that in all worlds out of some collection of worlds, $A$ is true.

As such, we can show that we can make $(1)$ true, but $(2)$ false: create a collection of two worlds, $w_1$ and $w_2$. Then assume that $A$ is true in $w_1$, but $A$ is false in $w_2$.

Now, $(1)$ is true, since in $w_1$, we have that $A$ is true, and hence $A \lor \neg A$ is truew in $w_1$ as well. In $w_2$ we have that $\neg A$ is true, and hence $A \lor \neg A$ is true in $w_2$ is true as well. So, $A \lor A$ is true in all worlds, and hence it is necessarily true. So, $(1)$ is true.

$(2)$, however is false.  We don't have that $A$ is necessarily true, since $A$ is not true in all worlds: $A$ is not true in $w_2$. Likewise, $\neg A$ is not true in $w_1$, and hence $\neg A$ is not necessarily true. Hence, both disjuncts from $(2)$ are false, so $(2)$ is false.

Comment: Bram28.- Thanks for this clear answer. A detail : I have already heard of a " definition" of "necessity" such as " A is necessarily true iff A is true in all possible worlds". Is the definiiton you provide at the beginning an alternative one or does it rely on  the definition I have heard of in the following way  : " a proposition that is true in all possible worlds is ipso facto true in all worlds belonging to a  finite collection of worlds." ?

Comment: @EleonoreSaintJames Well, in modal logic you may want to interpret the 'necessary' part as being constrained/relativized to a more restricted set of worlds, rather than simply all logically possible worlds.  This is what I want to do when I say: "within these constraints, it is necessary that ...": I clearly have a restricted set of possibilities in mind.  Of course, in this case, where we are merely trying to find a counterexample, it doesn't really matter: given that the premise is true in all possible worlds, I just need to find *some* possible worlds that made the conclusion false.

Comment: Thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 0):

For unknown $n\in\Bbb N$, let $A$ denote $n=1$. Neither $A$ nor $\neg A$ is necessarily true; each has a counterexample.

Comment: J.G. Sorry, I'm not used to the language of modal logic. What does this set B denote? Does "1" denote the truth-value ' true"?

Comment: @EleonoreSaintJames Ah! Forgive my now corrected typo.